# How do I determine the value of a generic variable at runtime?

Tags: swift, xcode, generics

The following snippet shows the generic variable 'A'.

I'm trying to figure out the source of nil being returned by this load().

Here's a the code snippet:

```
final class Cache {
    var storage = FileStorage()

    // 1) 'load': Read from the Cache:
    func load<A>(_ resource: Resource<A>) -> A? {
        print("--- LOAD ---")
        guard case .get = resource.method else { return nil }
        // Type of 'data' is optional.
        let diskData = storage[resource.cacheKey] // ...type: Data? (optional-Data).
        // Want to convert diskData to A? (optional-A):
        return diskData.flatMap(resource.parse) // ...cleaning data, removing nils.
    }

    // 2) 'save' to the Cache:
    func save<A>(_ data: Data, for resource: Resource<A>) {
        print("--- SAVE ---")
        guard case .get = resource.method else { return }
        self.storage[resource.cacheKey] = data
    }
}

// ----------------------------------

// MARK: -  Resource

public struct Resource<A> {
    public var url: URL
    public var parse: (Data) -> A? // ... convert Data to A?
    public var method: HttpMethod<Data> = .get

    public init(url: URL, parse: @escaping (Data) -> A?, method: HttpMethod<Data> = .get) {
        self.url = url
        self.parse = parse
        self.method = method
    }
}

// ----------------------------------
```

In the meantime, How I can determine the value of any generic variable during runtime-debugging?

That is, who do I determine the value of A?

*Note: code is from a shared source via 'Swift Talk' on objc.io.*

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please post code, data, logs, error message, etc as text (not images) so they are searchable

Comment: I've add a searchable code snippet per your request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find out what type `A` represents, print the type of a variable that has a type that include the generic type placeholder.

In your case, `resource` has type `Resource<A>` so:

```
p type(of: resource)
```

will show something like:

```
<ProjectName>.Resource<Int>
```

in which case `A` is `Int`.